# Multi-monitor Word 2010 features: is it possible to display one page per screen?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, microsoft-word-2010

I have two monitors on my desktop PC, at 1920x1080 and 1920x1200 of resolution respectively. Windows 7 is configured for multi-monitor desktop.

I am currently translating a text I wrote some months ago, replacing paragraphs as I write them in English. I would like to ease my work by displaying on the left monitor the page I'm editing and on the right monitor the page next to it, so I can avoid scrolling up and down when I'm reaching page end.

Do you think it's possible or do I really have to open two Word windows and scroll them independently?

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After googling and experimenting, here is how:

1. Open the document in Word on the first monitor
2. From View menu, click New Window. A new window appears
3. From one of the windows, click View Side by Side
4. Drag the other window to the other monitor, maximize both
5. Scroll each window down to the point you want to work
6. Click Synchronous scrolling

[image: Word Two Windows]

Answer (score 0):

My hunch is that it's not possible as both pages are part of the same document. My guess is that you'll have to use two documents.

Answer (score 0):

For two pages of the same document, the trick is to use the usual "split" mode of word, but defining your monitors as extending one above the other (and not side by side as you would usually do). 
It's a little confusing with cursor movement at the beginning, but it the only solution I found (after years of frustration).